# Build Bmin under VS2010 - need advice

Tags: visual-studio-2010, import, mingw32

There is a program called "https://code.google.com/p/bmin/", which I want to build under Visual Studio 2010 C++, as this is environment I'm used to work with all the time.

After getting sources, here is what I have:

- .git[folder]
- doc[folder]
- kernel[folder]
- qtgui[folder]
- shell[folder]
- .gitignore
- bmin.pro
- configure
- license
- main.cpp

Now, it depends on QT libraries, so I obtained QT from nokia and also installed visual studio 2010 qt addin. Still, I get lots of errors, if I just try and add all the project files into fresh Visual Studio TQ project.

So I need some general advices.

What was used to build this originally? Mingwc? What is proper way to import such code into visual studio 2010, what should I do about bmin.pro file and configure? There are also no 'make' file, so I'm a bit clueless how to start.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Many of errors looks like some syntax incompatibles: http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0VG4

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/bmin/wiki/Documentation_1_0) it is stated:

> **Windows:** For Windows the installer bmin-1.0.1-win32.exe is available [...]
>
> **Linux:** It is necessary to download the source code for Linux. The application depends on Qt library. This requires at least version 4.5 (version earlier than 4.5 will probably not compile). [...] First, you need to unpack the gzip archive. The translation is done in two steps. First, in the directory with unpacked source code, **run the configure file**. It creates a Makefile and it can pass the arguments presented in the following table. [...] After creating a Makefile you need to call the make command and then make install to save the executable file bmin into place.

So apparently you should think over your plan again and read the documentation first..

Comment: But that is for the Linux, not for the windows, and Visual Studio is not capable of running configuraton files?

Comment: Have you tried the windows installer from this page? VS is only capable of running project and solution files. I think they never wanted you to build the sources on windows, maybe due to licensing.

Comment: I want to build the sources, as I wanted to modify them later. I've looked through GPL license prior to this, and I don't think that is forbidden.